# Why table boxes are not rendering in a row in Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive email template for that I need 6 Books in a row.
The width of main table is 600px, **books table width is 15%** and **red highlighted table (for space between tables) width is 2%**. All tables are **left aligned**.

Email is working fine in browser but not rendering in properly in **Outlook** here is screenshot below.
There is 1px space around the red table, please suggest a fix so it renders in a row & works fine in outlook 2016 and also in other version.

**Outlook 2016 Example**

[image: Outlook 2016]

Note: I tried using single table with 6 `<td>` but it wasn't working in Andorid 4.4, so that is why I am using this table structure.

```css
/* MOBILE STYLES */

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
  table[class="responsive-table"] {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="responsive-table" align="center" bgcolor="yellow">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding: 0;">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>


            <table width="2%" height="10" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="red" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>


            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="2%" height="10" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="red" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="2%" height="10" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="red" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>


            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="2%" height="10" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="red" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>


            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="2%" height="10" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="red" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="15%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="85" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for table, I suggest you, not to use multiple tables inside a table, instead use TD.

It may resolve your issue.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
        /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
        table[class="responsive-table"] {
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="responsive-table" align="center" bgcolor="yellow">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
                  <td width="2%" bgcolor="red"></td>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
                  <td width="2%" bgcolor="red"></td>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
                  <td width="2%" bgcolor="red"></td>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
                  <td width="2%" bgcolor="red"></td>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
                  <td width="2%" bgcolor="red"></td>
                  <td width="15%">
                      <img src="http://placehold.jp/85x120.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[Snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1bq.png)

[Snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbbIC.png)

[Snapshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3m4B.png)

Comment: I was using this method but It is not working in Android 4.4. & Outlook (iOS 11.3.1)
Is there any other fix?

Comment: Will check and get back to you. (i'm travelling)